# MODx & Gallery component - how to handle non-existing albums?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Referrencing non-existing albums in the Gallery component results with the following warning & error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
/home/user/domain.com/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/17.include.cache.php on line 106

Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in 
/home/user/domain.com/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/17.include.cache.php on line 165
```

And here is how I reference albums:

```
[[!Gallery? &album=`[[*alias]]` &limit=`20` &thumbWidth=`90` &thumbHeight=`90`]]
```

Album names match page's aliases. Everything works fine if albums exist - I would like to display blank album (no content), if no matches found.

Any ideas? I am using MODX Revolution 2.2.4-pl (traditional).

Thanks, Luke

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
[[*alias:notempty=`[[!Gallery? &album=`[[*alias]]` &limit=`20` &thumbWidth=`90` &thumbHeight=`90`]]`]]
```

oh, wait! you are linking `[[*alias]]` to your album in Gallery. you should use your own TV like  `[[*album]]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it working...

Each page has corresponding gallery created with page's alias as gallery name. Some galleries are left blank.

Luke